# Longest palindrome in a string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, palindrome

I wrote the following function to find the longest palindrome in a string. It works fine but it won't work for words like "noon" or "redder".  I fiddled around and changed the first line in the `for` loop from:

```
var oddPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i);
```

to

```
var oddPal = centeredPalindrome(i-1, i);
```

and now it works, but I'm not clear on *why*. My intuition is that if you are checking an odd-length palindrome it will have one extra character in the beginning (I whiteboarded it out and that's the conclusion I came to). Am I on the right track with my reasoning?

```
var longestPalindrome = function(string) {

  var length = string.length;
  var result = "";

  var centeredPalindrome = function(left, right) {
    while (left >= 0 && right < length && string[left] === string[right]) {
      //expand in each direction.
      left--;
      right++;
    }

    return string.slice(left + 1, right);
  }; 

  for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    var oddPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i); 
    var evenPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i);

    if (oddPal.length > result.length)
      result = oddPal;
    if (evenPal.length > result.length)
      result = evenPal;
  }

  return "the palindrome is: " + result + " and its length is: " + result.length;
};
```

UPDATE:
After Paul's awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33677260/1324), I think it makes sense to change both variables for clarity:

```
var oddPal  = centeredPalindrome(i-1, i + 1);
var evenPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i+1);
```

Comment: YES - that finally makes sense. of course you would do i+1 for EVEN palindromes because their "center" would be 2 instead of 1 for odds. Thanks!

Comment: I think this might be more intuitive, editing above also: var oddPal = centeredPalindrome(i-1, i + 1);

    var evenPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i+1);

Comment: I just wanted to point out there is a fast linear time algorithm for this problem know as [`Manacher's algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have it backwards - if you output the "odd" palindromes (with your fix) you'll find they're actually even-length.

Imagine "noon", starting at the first "o" (left and right). That matches, then you move them both - now you're comparing the first "n" to the second "o". No good. But with the fix, you start out comparing both "o"s, and then move to both "n"s.

Example (with the `var oddPal = centeredPalindrome(i-1, i);` fix):

```js
var longestPalindrome = function(string) {

  var length = string.length;
  var result = "";

  var centeredPalindrome = function(left, right) {
    while (left >= 0 && right < length && string[left] === string[right]) {
      //expand in each direction.
      left--;
      right++;
    }

    return string.slice(left + 1, right);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    var oddPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i + 1);

    var evenPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i);

    if (oddPal.length > 1)
      console.log("oddPal: " + oddPal);
    if (evenPal.length > 1)
      console.log("evenPal: " + evenPal);

    if (oddPal.length > result.length)
      result = oddPal;
    if (evenPal.length > result.length)
      result = evenPal;
  }
  return "the palindrome is: " + result + " and its length is: " + result.length;
};

console.log(
  longestPalindrome("nan noon is redder")
);
```

Comment: I don't think this code checks for spaces. So if for example you ran  

`longestPalindrome("a level b");`    

you would get the longest palindrome as " level " with a length of 7.

Comment: True, though out of scope of (my reading of) the question. Definitely consider adding your own answer that solves that part of the problem.

Comment: Running this code gave me: _the palindrome is:  **noon**  and its length is: 6_ - should that be _redder_ instead?

Comment: As mentioned in an above comment, it doesn't treat spaces any differently than non-spaces. It's finding " noon " (leading and trailing space), which is 6 chars long just like redder. That's a thing that should be fixed, but a separate problem from this particular question.

Comment: Here loop must be run to less the length

for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) ==> for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)

Comment: @Prerana If we made that change, what would happen when we reference the `i + 1` element?

Answer (score 1):

## Here is another take on the subject.

- Checks to make sure the string provided is not a palindrome. If it is then we are done. ( Best Case )
- Worst case 0(n^2)

link to 
[gist](https://gist.github.com/wesleyduff/a791c784b07b58d0373a92cc7c7a1b16)

Use of dynamic programming. Break each problem out into its own method, then take the solutions of each problem and add them together to get the answer.

```
class Palindrome {
   constructor(chars){
     this.palindrome = chars;
     this.table = new Object();
     this.longestPalindrome = null;
     this.longestPalindromeLength = 0;

     if(!this.isTheStringAPalindrome()){
      this.initialSetupOfTableStructure();
     }
   }

   isTheStringAPalindrome(){
     const reverse = [...this.palindrome].reverse().join('');
     if(this.palindrome === reverse){
       this.longestPalindrome = this.palindrome;
       this.longestPalindromeLength = this.palindrome.length;
       console.log('pal is longest', );
       return true;
     }
   }

   initialSetupOfTableStructure(){
     for(let i = 0; i < this.palindrome.length; i++){
       for(let k = 0; k < this.palindrome.length; k++){
        this.table[`${i},${k}`] = false;
       }
     }
     this.setIndividualsAsPalindromes();
   }

   setIndividualsAsPalindromes(){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.palindrome.length; i++){
      this.table[`${i},${i}`] = true;
    }
    this.setDoubleLettersPlaindrome();
   }

   setDoubleLettersPlaindrome(){
     for(let i = 0; i < this.palindrome.length; i++){
       const firstSubstring = this.palindrome.substring(i, i + 1);
       const secondSubstring = this.palindrome.substring(i+1, i + 2);
      if(firstSubstring === secondSubstring){
       this.table[`${i},${i + 1}`] = true;

       if(this.longestPalindromeLength < 2){
         this.longestPalindrome = firstSubstring + secondSubstring;
         this.longestPalindromeLength = 2;
       }
      }
     }
     this.setAnyPalindromLengthGreaterThan2();
   }

   setAnyPalindromLengthGreaterThan2(){
     for(let k = 3; k <= this.palindrome.length; k++){
      for(let i = 0; i <= this.palindrome.length - k; i++){
        const j = i + k - 1;
        const tableAtIJ = this.table[`${i+1},${j-1}`];
        const stringToCompare = this.palindrome.substring(i, j +1);
        const firstLetterInstringToCompare = stringToCompare[0];
        const lastLetterInstringToCompare = [...stringToCompare].reverse()[0];
        if(tableAtIJ && firstLetterInstringToCompare === lastLetterInstringToCompare){

          this.table[`${i},${j}`] = true;

          if(this.longestPalindromeLength < stringToCompare.length){
            this.longestPalindrome = stringToCompare;
            this.longestPalindromeLength = stringToCompare.length;
          }
        }
      }
     }
   }

   printLongestPalindrome(){
     console.log('Logest Palindrome', this.longestPalindrome);
     console.log('from /n', this.palindrome );
   }

   toString(){
     console.log('palindrome', this.palindrome);
     console.log(this.table)
   }
 }

 // const palindrome = new Palindrome('lollolkidding');
 // const palindrome = new Palindrome('acbaabca');
 const palindrome = new Palindrome('acbaabad');
 palindrome.printLongestPalindrome();
 //palindrome.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be optimal if the largest palindrome is found earlier. 
Once its found it will exit both loops.

```
function isPalindrome(s) {
      //var rev = s.replace(/\s/g,"").split('').reverse().join('');  //to remove space
      var rev = s.split('').reverse().join('');
      return s == rev;
    }

    function longestPalind(s) {
      var maxp_length = 0,
        maxp = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var subs = s.substr(i, s.length);
        if (subs.length <= maxp_length) break; //Stop Loop for smaller strings
        for (var j = subs.length; j >= 0; j--) {
          var sub_subs = subs.substr(0, j);
          if (sub_subs.length <= maxp_length) break; // Stop loop for smaller strings
          if (isPalindrome(sub_subs)) {

              maxp_length = sub_subs.length;
              maxp = sub_subs;

          }
        }
      }
      return maxp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function longestPalindrome(str){
   var arr = str.split("");
   var endArr = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       var temp = "";
       temp = arr[i];
       for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
          temp += arr[j];
          if(temp.length > 2 && temp === temp.split("").reverse().join("")){
             endArr.push(temp);
          }
   }
}

var count = 0;
var longestPalindrome = "";
for(var i = 0; i < endArr.length; i++){
   if(count >= endArr[i].length){
     longestPalindrome = endArr[i-1]; 
   }
   else{
      count = endArr[i].length;
   }
 }
 console.log(endArr);
 console.log(longestPalindrome);
 return longestPalindrome;
}

longestPalindrome("abracadabra"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function longest_palindrome(s) {
  if (s === "") {
    return "";
  }
  let arr = [];
  let _s = s.split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < _s.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < _s.length; j++) {
      let word = _s.slice(0, j + 1).join("");
      let rev_word = _s
        .slice(0, j + 1)
        .reverse()
        .join("");
      if (word === rev_word) {
        arr.push(word);
      }
    }
    _s.splice(0, 1);
  }
  let _arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < _arr.length; i++) {
    if (_arr[arr.length - 1].length === _arr[i].length) {
      return _arr[i];
    }
  }
}

longest_palindrome('bbaaacc')
//This code will give you the first longest palindrome substring into the string
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let str = "HYTBCABADEFGHABCDEDCBAGHTFYW12345678987654321ZWETYGDE";
    let rev = str.split("").reverse().join("").trim();
    let len = str.length;
    let a="";
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
        for(let j = len ; j > i ; j--){
            a = rev.slice(i,j);
            if(str.includes(a)){
                result.push(a);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    result.sort((a,b) => { return b.length - a.length})
    let logPol = result.find((value)=>{
        return value === value.split('').reverse().join('') && value.length > 1
    })

    console.log(logPol);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please explain your solution.

Comment: 1st reverse the string apply operation on reversed string. double for loop for  iterating over the string.  Inner loop makes substring from reversed like "ABCDE" "ABCD" "ABC" "AB" if match in main string keep the string into array.  iterate loop for all the characters. Finally will get the matching string array. Arrange array based on length check the elements which are polindrome.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var longestPalindrome = function(string) {

  var length = string.length;
  var result = "";

  var centeredPalindrome = function(left, right) {
    while (left >= 0 && right < length && string[left] === string[right]) {
      //expand in each direction.
      left--;
      right++;
    }

    return string.slice(left + 1, right);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    var oddPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i + 1);

    var evenPal = centeredPalindrome(i, i);

    if (oddPal.length > 1)
      console.log("oddPal: " + oddPal);
    if (evenPal.length > 1)
      console.log("evenPal: " + evenPal);

    if (oddPal.length > result.length)
      result = oddPal;
    if (evenPal.length > result.length)
      result = evenPal;
  }
  return "the palindrome is: " + result + " and its length is: " + result.length;
};

console.log(longestPalindrome("n"));
```

This will give wrong output so this condition need to be taken care where there is only one character.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public string LongestPalindrome(string s) {
       return LongestPalindromeSol(s, 0, s.Length-1);
 }
 public static string LongestPalindromeSol(string s1, int start, int end)
 {
        if (start > end)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if (start == end)
        {
            char ch = s1[start];
            string s = string.Empty;
            var res = s.Insert(0, ch.ToString());
            return res;
        }
        if (s1[start] == s1[end])
        {
            char ch = s1[start];
            var res = LongestPalindromeSol(s1, start + 1, end - 1);
            res = res.Insert(0, ch.ToString());
            res = res.Insert(res.Length, ch.ToString());
            return res;
        }
        else
        {
            var str1 = LongestPalindromeSol(s1, start, end - 1);
            var str2 = LongestPalindromeSol(s1, start, end - 1);
            if (str1.Length > str2.Length)
            {
                return str1;
            }
            else
            {
                return str2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
This is in JS ES6. much simpler and works for almost all words .. Ive tried radar, redder, noon etc. 

const findPalindrome = (input) => {
  let temp = input.split('')
  let rev = temp.reverse().join('')

  if(input == rev){
    console.log('Palindrome', input.length)
  }
}
//i/p : redder
// "Palindrome" 6
```

Comment: it is simpler because you're not searching for a palindrome in the string but only if the string is a palindrome

Comment: @bobrobbob mmm i don't follow, how does it know if its a valid word or not... would it just looking for similar chars following each other? that seem completely useless and invalid, as they would actually be none words.